# Multiply all columns of one matrix by another matrix with bsxfun

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

I have two matrices `A` and `B`, both of size `4x4`. multiply the first column of `A` with all the other columns of `B` with:

```
bsxfun(@times, A(:,1),B)
```

but what I want to do is to repeat this operation for each column of `A`, *i.e* multiply all columns of `A` by all columns of `B`. How can I do this with `bsxfun` (without loops or `repmat`)?

Comment: `bsxfun` is so much fun!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by [permuting](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) the dimensions of one of the matrices to make it a 4x1x4 array:

```
permute(bsxfun(@times, A, permute(B, [1 3 2])), [1 3 2])
```

Comment: +1, but it seems like your edits produce a shifted result. I've corrected your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
>> n = size(A, 1);
>> res = arrayfun(@(x) A(:, x) * ones(1, n) .* B, 1 : n, 'UniformOutput', false)

res = 

    [4x4 double]    [4x4 double]    [4x4 double]    [4x4 double]
```

A remark: in Matlab "multiply" by default means matrix multiplication, which would be simply `res = A' * B`. What you asked is Element wise multiplication.