# Matlab create matrix by iterating the same command several times without for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a code like this:

```
A = [sparse(round(rand(4,4)))];
B = [sparse(round(rand(1,4)))];
C = [bsxfun(@minus,A(1,:),B); bsxfun(@minus,A(2,:),B); bsxfun(@minus,A(3,:),B); bsxfun(@minus,A(4,:),B);]
```

Is is possible to somehow define C this way for a large amount rows (so that I cannot physically print the command this way) WITHOUT a loop (because a loop would take an excessively long time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One another options:

If you prefer to keep a sparse matrix:

```
C = A - repmat(B,size(A,1),1); %but slower than the bsxfun version.
```

Comment: The top one will fail since the dimensions must agree. (Whether the matrices are full or sparse is irrelevant here).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, so only octave can manage this "row wise" operation ?

Comment: Ah, yes. Octave does indeed perform "broadcasting" in this situation, but matlab needs to be instructed specifically.

Comment: don't *delete*, edit it to leave the repmat solution which is correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a matrix and a row vector to `bsxfun`, it will automatically apply the vector to all rows of the matrix, so just use:

```
C = bsxfun(@minus, A, B);
```

This will substract the row vector B to all rows of matrix A, no matter how many rows you have.

EDIT: If you have two matrices instead of a Matrix and a Vector, you can either use permutations or `arrayfun`. Take a look at:

[Multiply all columns of one matrix by another matrix with bsxfun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959675/multiply-all-columns-of-one-matrix-by-another-matrix-with-bsxfun)

Comment: Thank you, but if also B is a matrix and I would like to apply the bsx function for all the vectors of B what you just said is not correct anymore, is it?

Comment: You can then use permutations, take a look at my edit in the answer.

Comment: By the way if you already marked another answer as accepted it means you already solved your problem.